# Redux Action is not been dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react - redux application. Now I faced an issue to dispatch the action. The following code cannot dispatch the generateReport action.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { submit, getFormValues, isValid } from "redux-form";
import { generateReport } from "../actions/generateActions";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const docsButtonStyle = {
  position: "fixed",
  marginBottom: "0.5em",
  marginLeft: "0.1em",
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  animation: "back-to-docs 1.5s ease-in-out infinite",
  zIndex: 6
};

class ButtonGroup extends Component {
  generate = () => {
    this.props.generateReport(this.props.values);
  };     

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={docsButtonStyle}>
        <Button.Group vertical>              
          <Button animated="fade" color="teal" onClick={this.generate}>
            <Button.Content hidden>Generate</Button.Content>
            <Button.Content visible>
              <Icon name="chart bar" size="large" />
            </Button.Content>
          </Button>
        </Button.Group>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  values: getFormValues("privateForm")(state),
  valid: isValid("privateForm")(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  generateReport,
  remoteSubmit: () => {
    dispatch(submit("privateForm"));
  }
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ButtonGroup);
```

generateActions.js

```
export const generateReport = values => async dispatch => {
  console.log("test");
  try {
    dispatch(generateReportBegin());
    const response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/submit`, values);
    dispatch(generateReportSuccess());
  } catch (error) {

  }
};
```

If I change connect function into

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {generateReport}
)(ButtonGroup);
```

It works. Can anyone tell me why it does not work in the first situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to different behavior of `connect` function [depending of passed](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object) arguments to `mapDispatchToProps`

1. If you pass function it will be called with `dispatch` as first argument and resulting object will be merged to `props`. In this case it is assumed that in supplied function you prepare `dispatch` calls for every action.

   In code

   ```
   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
       generateReport,
       remoteSubmit: () => {
           dispatch(submit("privateForm"));
       }
   });
   ```

   `mapDispatchToProps` will be called with `dispatch` as argument and produces object with 2 functions. `remoteSubmit` should work correctly as it is bound to `dispatch`. But `generateReport` is just some external function which is passed as is. So on any call to `this.props.generateReport` just function will be returned taking `dispatch` as argument. Redux belives that you already prepared everything needed for dispatching in `mapDispatchToProps` so it does nothing.
2. If you pass object as `mapDispatchToProps` (what is you do in second example), `connect` will call [`bindActionCreators`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) for you and wrap `generateReport` inside `dispatch` call. So it works.

To make both actions work you should wrap all action creators in `dispatch` calls.

Possible ways to do so

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    generateReport: bindActionCreators(generateReport, dispatch),
    remoteSubmit: () => {
        dispatch(submit("privateForm"));
    }
});
```

Another way

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    generateReport: (value) => dispatch(generateReport(value)),
    remoteSubmit: () => {
        dispatch(submit("privateForm"));
    }
});
```

Or call `mapDispatchToProps` with one object containing all action creators. In this case `connect` will call `bindActionCreators` for you.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    generateReport,
    remoteSubmit: () => submit("privateForm")
    }
```

Comment: Hi Fyodor, thanks for your explanation. This works.